# Sending ExtJS datastore parameter to CI controller

Tags: codeigniter, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS and I'm stuck with ExtJS datastore.
I'm using ExtJS with CodeIgniter and I want to send ExtJS datastore.load() parameter to my codeigniter's controller to process some query.
How can I do that?

Here is my ExtJS datastore proxy:

```
var dataProxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url: 'index.php/cStart/js_listPegawai/',
    method: 'POST'
});
```

and this is my controller code:

```
var $queryNama = "";
function js_listPegawai()
    {
        $this->load->model('MPegawai');
        $Pegawai = $this->MPegawai->listPegawai($queryNama);
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

```
blahblahStore.load({
  params: {
    blahblah: 'blah'
  }
})
```